# What happened to the latest gender question?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

There was just a question referring to gender and downvotes that has just disappeared; in fact, it's not even in the [Recently Deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today) queue (10ks only)?

Where did it go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214402/why-do-female-users-do-not-get-down-votes-like-male-users-on-so

> This question was voluntarily removed by its author.

And as 10K or mods can see, here is the actual reason as written by the OP: ([high rep user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks) on SO)

> OK. Guys thanks for you assistance. I thing I am alien to this site. Better to run back to SO :)

(typo in original comment please don't fix)

Comment: I had no idea that self-deleted questions didn't show in the just Deleted queue.

Comment: @LanceRoberts you mean [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=today) under "Recently Deleted"? Either cache or by design, this does make some sense. :)

Comment: By the way, it still appears in [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=Why+do+female+users+do+not+get+down+votes+like+male+users+on+SO)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, yep, there.  It does make some sense, but as much as I patrol that list I never caught that before.